# Scrollable DIV scrolls to top when TD is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an interesting problem that I cannot seem to find an answer for on Google. I have a scrollable div that a simple table in it. There are 'heading' rows ('.sl-bucket') that when clicked the script shows the associated rows below that, hiding other shown rows. In Chrome and IE, there is no issues. In Firefox on a fresh load, when you click the first element, it scrolls the div back to the top. Everything else works great after that.

Any thoughts on how I could fix this?

Here is the example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kenkell/73WkQ/1/).

Here is my javscript:

```
$(window).on('click', '.sl-bucket', function() {
        var bucket = $(this).attr('rel');
        if ($('.sl-'+bucket).is(':visible') == false) {
            $('.sl-unitRow:visible').hide();
            $('.sl-'+bucket).show();
        } else {
            $('.sl-'+bucket).hide();
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: I don't see that effect in Firefox.

Comment: I am able to replicate on FF 20.

Comment: It works for me, tested in FF, CH and IE...

Comment: Remove your duplicate ID's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working for me by using

```
$('.sl-'+bucket).css("display", "block");
```

instead of

```
$('.sl-'+bucket).show();
```